# html select only returning 1st option

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

Normally I can find an answer on here when I run into an issue but the answers in a similar post do not apply to what I am doing. I am using vb.net 2017 for this project.

I have a page with an html select dropdown that is databinded to a sqldatasource control. The select text is binded to the colorname field and the value is binded to the forecolor field. I used the text to set the background color of an html input and the value of the input. I use the value to set the forecolor of the mentioned input textbox. While this does work when I select anything option the select returns only the second 'option' value. The onchange function is a javascript function that submits the form so I can get the onchange event to fire.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 textalignright">
            <label>Background Color</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <select id="cbgcolor" runat="server" class="rcorners input" onchange="GetSelectedTextValue()" datasourceid="SqlDataSource2" datatextfield="colorname" datavaluefield="forecolor">

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <input id="ibgcolor" runat="server" type="text" class="rcorners input" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedTextValue() {
        form1.submit();
    }
</script>
```

The code behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    AddHandler cbgcolor.ServerChange, AddressOf Color_ServerChange
End Sub

Sub Color_ServerChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'ibgcolor.Style.Clear()
    ibgcolor.Style.Add("background-color", cbgcolor.Items(cbgcolor.SelectedIndex).Text)
    ibgcolor.Style.Add("color", cbgcolor.Value)
    ibgcolor.Value = cbgcolor.Items(cbgcolor.SelectedIndex).Text
End Sub
```

When I run this page and I select any option I see it load then reverts to the second option in the options. The first option is just text saying select color.

Edit:
Here is the DropDownList on the web side

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="acbgcolor" runat="server" CssClass="rcorners input">
    <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="--Background Color--"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="AliceBlue"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="AntiqueWhite"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Aqua"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Aquamarine"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Azure"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Beige"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Bisque"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The selectedindexchanged event

```
Private Sub acbgcolor_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles acbgcolor.SelectedIndexChanged
    ibgcolor.Style.Clear()
    ibgcolor.Style.Add("background-color", acbgcolor.Items(acbgcolor.SelectedIndex).Text)
    ibgcolor.Style.Add("color", acbgcolor.Items(acbgcolor.SelectedIndex).Value)
    ibgcolor.Value = acbgcolor.Items(acbgcolor.SelectedIndex).Text
End Sub
```

Created a new project to test with and the behavior is the same as mentioned above with the asp dropdownlist, whichever option I choose it goes back to index 0.

Here is the asp page in full

```
<html lang=en>
<head runat="server">
<link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="--Background Color--"> 
</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="AliceBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="AntiqueWhite"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Aqua"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Aquamarine"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Azure"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Beige"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Bisque"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Black"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="BlanchedAlmond"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Blue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="BlueViolet"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Brown"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="BurlyWood"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="CadetBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Chartreuse"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Chocolate"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Coral"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="CornflowerBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Cornsilk"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Crimson"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Cyan"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkCyan"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkGoldenrod"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="DarkGray"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="DarkKhaki"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkMagenta"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkOliveGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="DarkOrange"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkOrchid"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkRed"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="DarkSalmon"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="DarkSeaGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkSlateBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkSlateGray"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="DarkTurquoise"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DarkViolet"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DeepPink"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="DeepSkyBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="DimGray"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="DodgerBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Firebrick"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="FloralWhite"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="ForestGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Fuchsia"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Gainsboro"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="GhostWhite"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Gold"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Goldenrod"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Gray"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Green"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="GreenYellow"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Honeydew"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="HotPink"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="IndianRed"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Indigo"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Ivory"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Khaki"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Lavender"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LavenderBlush"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LawnGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LemonChiffon"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightCoral"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightCyan"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightGoldenrodYellow"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightGray"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightPink"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightSalmon"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightSeaGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightSkyBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="LightSlateGray"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightSteelBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LightYellow"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Lime"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="LimeGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Linen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Magenta"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Maroon"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="MediumAquamarine"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="MediumBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="MediumOrchid"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="MediumPurple"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="MediumSeaGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="MediumSlateBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="MediumSpringGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="MediumTurquoise"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="MediumVioletRed"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="MidnightBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="MintCream"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="MistyRose"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Moccasin"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="NavajoWhite"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Navy"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="OldLace"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Olive"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="OliveDrab"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Orange"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="OrangeRed"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Orchid"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="PaleGoldenrod"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="PaleGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="PaleTurquoise"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="PaleVioletRed"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="PapayaWhip"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="PeachPuff"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Peru"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Pink"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Plum"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="PowderBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Purple"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Red"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="RosyBrown"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="RoyalBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="SaddleBrown"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Salmon"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="SandyBrown"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="SeaGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="SeaShell"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Sienna"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Silver"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="SkyBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="SlateBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="SlateGray"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Snow"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="SpringGreen"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="SteelBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Tan"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Teal"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Thistle"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="white" Text="Tomato"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Turquoise"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Violet"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Wheat"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="White"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="WhiteSmoke"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Yellow"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="YellowGreen"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <select id="test" runat="server">
        <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
        <option class="bg-dark" value="1">one</option>
        <option class="bg-light" value="2">two</option>
        <option class="bg-red" value="3">three</option>
    </select>
    <select id="Select1" name="Select1" runat="server" onchange="GetSelectedTextValue()">
        <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
        <option class="bg-dark" value="1">one</option>
        <option class="bg-light" value="2">two</option>
        <option class="bg-red" value="3">three</option>

    </select>

    <input id="Text1" type="text" value="" runat="server" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedTextValue() {

        form1.submit();

        return false;

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code behind

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not (Page.IsPostBack) Then

    End If
    AddHandler Select1.ServerChange, AddressOf Select1_ServerChange
End Sub


Sub Select1_ServerChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Text1.Value = Select1.Value & ", " & Select1.Items(Select1.SelectedIndex).Text
End Sub

Private Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Text1.Style.Add("background-color", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString)
    Text1.Style.Add("color", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    Text1.Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString
End Sub
End Class
```

The html select on the right will populate the input but the asp dropdown just goes back to index 0.

Comment: Have you tried using the <asp:DropDownList instead? It has an autopostback option where you don't need to write any javascript.

Comment: Thank you for responding lotus but in this case the html select is what I am working with. This wouldn't be an issue with the asp:DropDownList.

Comment: I removed the databinding and added the options manually to see if there would be a difference in behavior but that didn't change the behavior.

Comment: " the html select is what I am working with."...we can see that, but the question was why not use the DropdownList control? Is there anything preventing you from doing that?

Comment: The reason for not using the asp:Dropdown is for personal knowledge of working with the html select and I find that the html select accepts css styling better than the asp:DropDown.

Comment: I put in the asp:DropDownList in place of the html select and I am getting the same results, no matter what I choose the selectedindex is always 1. Would it be better to use the textchanged event vs the selectedindexchange event?

Comment: So there is something going on in the postback that keeps reverting the selectedindex back to 1. I turned off autopostback on the asp:DropDownList and when I select an option it stays selected. Is it possible for the postback to fire twice causing the dropdown to reload?

Comment: @DaleRekow the reason is that you have same value `black` for all the dropdown options. You need to have unique values for options.

Comment: I will give that a try and see what happens. I didn't see your comment until after I did this last edit. Thank you for your response Mohsin

Comment: @Mohsin-Mehmood Thank you for your answer. That took care of the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @DaleRekow the reason is that you have same value black for all the dropdown options. You need to have unique values for options. – Mohsin Mehmood

This is the correct answer for the situation I was having. Thank you Mohsin

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused due to duplicate values of dropdownlist options. For example the following code has all ListItems with value black.

```
 <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="AliceBlue"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="AntiqueWhite"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Aqua"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="black" Text="Aquamarine"></asp:ListItem>
```

So even when user selects the option with display text Aquamarine the AliceBlue option will be selected as it is the first option with value black.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `value` attribute was being changed after selection to a value which did not align to any of the options. In this case the browser simply defaults to the first option being selected.

In my case `value` was being changed to `"5"` but the option was `5`. Apparently in HTML this was not good enough; fixing the type also fixed the select.